# React.js Context API: useContext is returning null inside custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-custom-hooks

I'm trying to create & use a custom hook for a React Context. Inside this hook, I'm trying to pass the defined context, `SectionContext`, into `useContext` , like so:

```
export const useSectionContext= () => {
  const context = useContext<TSectionContext | null>(SectionContext); // Why is this null?

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("Must use useSectionContext within the context of SectionProvider.");
  }
  return context;
};
```

I initialized `SectionContext` & a Provider, like so:

```
export const SectionContext = createContext<TSectionContext | null>(null);

export const SectionProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [allDogs, setAllDogs] = useState<Dog[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<Tab>("all-dogs");

  useEffect(() => {
    Requests.getAllDogs()
      .then(setAllDogs)
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  // Helper functions that aren't relevant to this question
  
  // sectionContextValues below is an object containing helper functions & state values
  
  return (
    <SectionContext.Provider value={sectionContextValues}>
      {children}
    </SectionContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In the App.tsx file, I am then trying to wrap the `<Section>` component inside this provider, like so:

```
<SectionProvider>
    <Section label={"Dogs: "}>
      {activeTab === "no-dogs" ? <CreateDogForm /> : <Dogs />}
    </Section>
  </SectionProvider>
```

The error I am encountering is stemming from the fact that the `useContext` in the first code block above is returning `null`, and I haven't yet figured out why.

There are no problems with the imports or exports, btw. I also tried setting the initial value of `SectionContext` to undefined, but got the same result.

If someone could provide me with some insight as to why this could be happening, I would love to hear it. Please, let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Comment: What component is calling `useSectionContext`? And if it's not one of the ones shown so far, where is it relative to the `<SectionProvider>`?

Comment: @NicholasTower I called it in App.tsx, which is a parent component. I think I did it correctly here, but I'm not sure. In the last code block above, you can see the Dogs & CreateDogForm components; I am also destructuring some values of that hook in these two components. These are both children of the Section component, which is a child of App, and is wrapped inside SectionProvider, so I'm not sure why it's returning null.

Comment: Well is most likely because you are setting the initial value to null in createContext, most likely the value changes after the app starts and hence why you get the error, I will update wherever you're using the sectionContextValues to do a check like if (sectionContextValues) so you don't get errors on the initial context value

Answer (score 0):

I learned that I cannot call `useSectionContext` in the same component I am importing `SectionProvider`. In my case, I had to wrap the necessary components inside `SectionProvider` in the parent of App.tsx, which is main.tsx. In the end, this is what my code looked like:

```
// in main.tsx:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import "./App.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import { App } from "./App";
import { SectionProvider } from "./sectionProvider";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Toaster />
    <SectionProvider>
      <App />
    </SectionProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
// in App.tsx:
import { Section } from "./Components/Section";
import { Dogs } from "./Components/Dogs";
import { CreateDogForm } from "./Components/CreateDogForm";
import { useSectionContext } from "./useSectionContext";

export function App() {
  const { activeTab } = useSectionContext();
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: "skyblue" }}>
      <header>
        <h1>pup-e-picker (Functional)</h1>
      </header>
      <Section label={"Dogs: "}>
        {activeTab === "no-dogs" ? <CreateDogForm /> : <Dogs />}
      </Section>
    </div>
  );
}
```